# How to delete all products list in invoice lines?

Tags: odoo, openerp-7

[image]I created lots of products with create and edit option in accounts invoice line, now when i go for search more option all of my products list appears. How do I delete it now? I have attached the image[image]

Comment: Then what you want is to remove the option "Search more..."?

Comment: refer this it's paid module in odoo apps. https://www.odoo.com/apps/modules/8.0/web_o2m_delete_multi/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mentioned that you created **New** products with **Create And Edit** option. So all the newly created products will be added to the list of products.

-->And if you want to remove these products you can either remove them from **GUI**  or from   **DATABASE**.

--> Open the **Products** in **LIST VIEW**

-->Select the products that you want to delete and from **ACTION** menu click on **delete**

> **Option 1: Delete products from GUI**[image]
>
> **Option 2: Delete products from database.**[image: Select the products you want to delete and from **ACTION** menu click on **delete**]
>   [image]